# Checkov fails on Terraform for GCP PostgreSQL's data flags for `pgAudit ` and `log_min_messages`

Tags: postgresql, logging, terraform, google-cloud-sql, checkov

I am getting the 3 below Chokov's failed tests:

```
Check: CKV_GCP_109: "Ensure the GCP PostgreSQL database log levels are set to ERROR or lower"
    FAILED for resource: google_sql_database_instance.cloud_sql
    File: /cloud_sql.tf:1-74
    Guide: https://docs.prismacloud.io/en/enterprise-edition/policy-reference/google-cloud-policies/logging-policies-1/bc-google-cloud-109

        Code lines for this resource are too many. Please use IDE of your choice to review the file.
Check: CKV_GCP_110: "Ensure pgAudit is enabled for your GCP PostgreSQL database"
    FAILED for resource: google_sql_database_instance.cloud_sql
    File: /cloud_sql.tf:1-74
    Guide: https://docs.prismacloud.io/en/enterprise-edition/policy-reference/google-cloud-policies/logging-policies-1/bc-google-cloud-110

        Code lines for this resource are too many. Please use IDE of your choice to review the file.
Check: CKV_GCP_55: "Ensure PostgreSQL database 'log_min_messages' flag is set to a valid value"
    FAILED for resource: google_sql_database_instance.cloud_sql
    File: /cloud_sql.tf:1-74
    Guide: https://docs.prismacloud.io/en/enterprise-edition/policy-reference/google-cloud-policies/cloud-sql-policies/bc-gcp-sql-6
```

I followed the Pao Alto's links and changed my code accordingly:

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "cloud_sql" {
  name             = "cloud-sql"
  database_version = "POSTGRES_15"
  region           = var.region
  project          = var.project_id

  settings {
    tier = "db-f1-micro"

    backup_configuration {
      enabled = true
    }
    ip_configuration {
      ipv4_enabled = false
      require_ssl     = false
      private_network = "projects/${var.project_id}/global/networks/${var.network}"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_statement"
      value = "all"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_lock_waits"
      value = "on"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_connections"
      value = "on"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_checkpoints"
      value = "on"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_disconnections"
      value = "on"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_hostname"
      value = "on"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_min_error_statement"
      value = "ERROR"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_min_messages"
      value = "ERROR"
    }
#    database_flags {
#      name  = "log_min_messages"
#      value = "DEBUG5"
#    }
#    database_flags {
#      name  = "enable_pgaudit"
#      value = "on"
#    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "pgaudit.log"
      value = "'all'"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_duration"
      value = "on"
    }
  }
  deletion_protection = false
  depends_on          = [google_service_networking_connection.private_vpc_connection]
}
```

However, the checks are still failing.

I have tried a few different things.

For **CKV_GCP_110** I tried adding:

```
    database_flags {
      name  = "enable_pgaudit"
      value = "on"
    }
```

or removing a single quotation in value:

```
    database_flags {
      name  = "pgaudit.log"
      value = "all"  // was "'all'"
    }
```

For **CKV_GCP_109** and **CKV_GCP_55** I tried various values like `ERROR` or `DEBUG5`.
I also tried adding:

```
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_min_error_statement"
      value = "ERROR"
    }
```

The checks are still failing.

Comment: Hello!

Did you try to contrast the flags on your Terraform code with the database you create ones? You can follow these [steps](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/flags#view_current_values_of_database_flags) for doing so through Console, gcloud or REST. 

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Sounds like a good idea. I raised 2 issues on checkov's GitHub and received quick help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to pass **CKV_GCP_109** and **CKV_GCP_55** both of the below flags are necessary with values in lowercase.

```
   database_flags {
      name  = "log_min_error_statement"
      value = "error"
    }
    database_flags {
      name  = "log_min_messages"
      value = "error"
    }
```

For **CKV_GCP_110** both of the below flags are necessary(pay attention to quotation marks in values):

```
database_flags {
  name  = "enable_pgaudit"
  value = "on"
}
database_flags {
  name  = "pgaudit.log"
  value = "'all'"
}
```

References:

https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov/issues/6057
https://github.com/bridgecrewio/checkov/issues/6058